# ruby cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I know this has been done to death and it seems like there are a dozen questions about this problem on SO but I'm just not finding a working answer.

I'm using RVM to manage my rubies, but I'm not using any custom gemsets. I did a `gem install passivedns-client` and it installed without giving me any errors. However I'm not able to load the gem in any scripts or even in irb. Here is the output of some commands that might give context.

```
Machine_name:~ user_name$ gem list passive

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

passivedns-client (1.4.1)

Machine_name:~ user_name$ rvm gemdir
/Users/user_name/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3

Machine_name:~ user_name$ which irb
/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/irb

Machine_name:~ user_name$ which gem
/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/gem

Machine_name:~ user_name$ irb
2.1.3 :001 > $LOAD_PATH
 => ["/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0", "/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0", "/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0", "/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0", "/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0", "/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin13.0"] 

2.1.3 :002 > require 'passivedns-client'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- passivedns-client
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.1.3 :003 > 

Machine_name:~ user_name$ rvm current
ruby-2.1.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something is just wrong with the namespace of this specific gem and not your `$LOAD_PATH`.  I diagnosed it using `bundle open` but after a few attempts I was able to get it to by:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'passivedns'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- passivedns
from /Users/anthonyross/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
[2] pry(main)> require 'passivedns/client/version'
=> true
[3] pry(main)> c = PassiveDNS::Client.new
=> #<PassiveDNS::Client:0x007f8e0e83b820>
[4] pry(main)>
```

Comment: Good to know that I'm not just a drooling idiot. That worked for me as well.

Comment: Fire off a pull request to fix that namespace issue, that's not very good practice!